# PyScripter - Why does this work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

I am using the PyScripter integrated development environment and taking courses using Python 2.7.

Why does `number = input("some input text")` immediately display the python input dialog when the program is ran? Wouldn't we have to execute it? Because really, it's just setting a variable to a python input. It never says to execute it? Is `number` not just any variable?

There's a mini-forum which the site that I go to has, but have not received an answer in 5 days, so I came here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `x = print('Hello World')`. Assuming this is python 3 (as this is a syntax error in python 2) the value `None` will be stored in `x` which isn't particularly useful. Next, I'm not sure what you mean by "execute `x`", and the next piece of code `print x` is a syntax error in python 3.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. It would be like saying `print(print("Hello World"))` with what I was doing. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `number` is variable and nothing more. See [documentation on input()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Well then why does it display the input when the program is ran? Isn't a variable just storage in memory?

Comment: The `input()` function has the side effect of displaying the input prompt in addition to returning a value.

Comment: I see. So wherever it is in the program, it's still going to run because it holds more importance?

Comment: When a line containing a call to the `input()` function, or any other function, is executed that function will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

python is just kind off a simple language, it does not need variable declaration for example.
But it's better that it automatically asks your input instead that you have to write the code for starting the variable

Comment: Well then why if I say `x = print("Hello")` I have to `print x`?